# mailx command considering multiple cc mail address as to address

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to send an email with attachments to more than one email address in the `CC` section, but it is considering the first mail address as `CC` and rest of them as the `to addresses`.

```
mailx -a "${p_target_file}" -s "${p_subject}" -r "${p_fromid}" -c $p_mail_ccid $p_mail_to
```

I am expecting the attachment, body, and subject to be sent to one email address and multiple CC email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Each additional CC address needs to be appended with it's own `-c` or as a comma separated list, ideally enclosed in quotes.  You likley need to look into what values are contained in `$p_mail_ccid`

Answer (score 0):

It's working when i modified it like:

```
mailx -a "${p_target_file}" -s "${p_subject}" -c "${p_mail_ccid}" -r "${p_fromid}"  $p_mail_to
```